# Clickable elements too close together & Content wider than screen in Google search console

Tags: php, html, laravel, responsive

My website is fully responsive and the bottom positions are fine but the Google search console says my website is not mobile-friendly because of the following error:

Clickable elements too close together
Content wider than screen

my website is https://www.swayss.com

Comment: This is not a website maintenance service, please read [ask] and create a [mcve] of the issue **in the question itself**

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a Lighthouse report on Chrome and examine it. As I can see from my Chromium browser it tells me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lDas.png). Beside the mobile compatibility your website is super slow. It is literally choking until my browser caches website's data. You can find other useful data about performance and [other things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6NKN.png) on a Lighthouse report.

1. Absolute Values

> Content wider than screen

You are probably using absolute pixel values on your css files which broke your content. You can put them inside a container or edit your css rules.

2. Badly designed UI(?)

> Clickable elements too close together

Check your Lighthouse report. It tells exactly which elements are problematic. Also "learn more" hyperlinks redirects you to useful guides. Check those.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, Serdar for help. But I have removed all the position: absolute in my CSS but the problem remains the same. And also I check the mobile view in the Lighthouse but can you please let me know how can I find which items the Google Search Console exactly means by too close. For site performance am trying to solve it as well.

Comment: I didn't meant "position: absolute" rules. I meant rules like "width: 1200px". It means you are using an absolute value,  a very strict rule. Maybe web page doesn't fit or maybe it's harder to adapt responsive style for other elements in your page. In Lighthouse check the SEO for things you are looking for Google Search Console warnings. It gives you a list of elements under "Mobile Friendly section". Besides your question doesn't follow community guidelines. Use the links that @AlonEitan showed and I hope you can post such question with the data you get from Lighthouse report.